Airline baggage size?
If I have allowence of 23x2 check-in luggage, what should the dimension of the check-in luggage be?

Which airline and between which airports?

What has your research to date revealed? This varies hugely between airlines. Sites like Upgraded Points provide comparison information but you should always check the website of the airline(s) concerned.

I’m voting to close this question because there’s no evidence of the OP having done even cursory  research, and the question does not even provide crucial information such as the airline(s) concerned.

There can be a lot of variation in the number, size and weight allowances, based on the airline, the class of travel, and sometimes the specific flight.
For checked luggage, the most common (but definitely not universal) maximum size allowance is that the sum of length, width and height should be below 158 cm (62 inches). Many others push that to 203 cm (80 inches), and there are quite a few exceptions, so you must check what your airline says.
Note that 2 x 23 kg means two bags of 23 kg each, you cannot have one piece weighing 46 kg. While you may often do things like 30 + 10, this is not always the case, and there is very often an absolute max weight of 32 kg per piece. Again, check with your airline.
